# Using JOptionPane with Xtend

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, xtend

I realize it might be a very stupid question, but how do I use JOptionPane with Xtend? I can't figure it out and I've been trying to get it working for a while now.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getContentPane(), message);` doesn't seem to work.

Eclipse gives me this error: `The method or field JOptionPane is undefined for the type MyClassName`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `The method or field JOptionPane is undefined..`  Make sure there is an import for it.

Comment: I'm sure there is an import for it. I'm working on providing a suitable SSCCE, I didn't do that because I thought JOptionPane should simply be used in another manner with Xtend. I'm very new to Java and can't really get the feel of it yet, I've to admit. Ehh, maybe I should just go back to .NET...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods or fields are accessed by double colons in Xtend:

```
JOptionPane::showMessageDialog(..)
```

Please refer to the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#staticAccess) for details.